# Составить регулярное выражение для изменениq URL

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

В дампе БД URL хранятся ввиде

[https://domain-name.ru/blahblah\"](https://domain-name.ru/blahblah%5C%22)

Нужно в конце каждого URL добавить закрывающий слэш через "Найти и заменить" в Notepad++

[https://domain-name.ru/blahblah/\"](https://domain-name.ru/blahblah/%5C%22)

Помогите составить регулярное выражение.

Comment: я так понимаю, 1 - blahblah везде разные, 2 - просто заменить \ на /\ не помогает, верно?

Comment: зачем тут регулярное выражение? достаточно заменить `\"` на `/\"`

Comment: Тагда там заменялся и все другие входжения типа target=\"_blank\"

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать так:
Найти:

```
(https:\/\/\S+)(\\")
```

Заменить на:

```
$1/\\"
```

Должно сработать

**UPDATE** (в ответ на Ваш комментарий)

```
(https:\/\/\S+?)(\\?\")
```

Заменять на то же самое.

Comment: Тут я забыл один нюанс указать, в дампе есть часть ссылок с закрывающим слешем.
И такой вариант замены добавит второй закрывающий слэш.

Comment: Добавил проверку